# Comparação com o if

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pessoal o que está errado no codigo, fiz uma função que chama um css caso um valor seja superior a 5 , o valor superior funciona porem o inferior que seria 3 onde apareceria outra css não funciona segue o codigo

```
SetInterval(function () {
roundedValue = Math.round( parseFloat( sensorValor ) * 100) / 100;
// roundedValue = math.round(parseFloat($('#testValue').val()( * 100 / 100;
if ((roundedValue >= 5) $$ testEnable ) {
$('#pag-1').hide();
$('#pag-2').show();
testEnable = false;
consolo.Log('teste ok!')
}

if ((roundedValue <= 3) $$ testEnable ) {
$('#pag-1').hide();
$('#pag-4').show();
testEnable = false;
consolo.Log('teste ok!')
}
```

tem alguma coisa errada no comparativo?

Comment: `$$` não seria `&&`? Leia mais em [operados lógicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: Além do erro observado pelo @Marconi, falta também a chave de fechamento da função. Posta o código HTML também para que possamos ter mais embasamento para ajudar a corrigir o problema.

Comment: Seu código está faltando `});` no final da linha e trocar `$$` por `&&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o código ficaria correto da seguinte forma:

```
SetInterval(function () {
    roundedValue = Math.round( parseFloat( sensorValor ) * 100) / 100;
    // roundedValue = math.round(parseFloat($('#testValue').val()( * 100 / 100);
    if (roundedValue >= 5 && testEnable ) {
        $('#pag-1').hide();
        $('#pag-2').show();
        testEnable = false;
        console.log('teste ok!')
    }

    else if (roundedValue <= 3 && testEnable ) {
        $('#pag-1').hide();
        $('#pag-4').show();
        testEnable = false;
        console.log('teste ok!')
    }
});
```

Comment: Brigadão amigo, funcionou perfeito agora

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você deva substituir seu código por este:

```
SetInterval(function() {
  roundedValue = Math.round(parseFloat(sensorValor) * 100) / 100;
  // roundedValue = math.round(parseFloat($('#testValue').val()( * 100 / 100;
  if (roundedValue >= 5 && testEnable) {
    $('#pag-1').hide();
    $('#pag-2').show();
    testEnable = false;
    console.Log('teste ok!')
  }

  if (roundedValue <= 3 && testEnable) {
    $('#pag-1').hide();
    $('#pag-4').show();
    testEnable = false;
    console.Log('teste ok!')
  }
});
```

Abraço jovem.

Answer (score 1):

Fica difícil saber o que você quer fazer com este código, mas acredito que o código abaixo pode lhe ajudar.

```js
(function () {
  var value = 4;
  var pag1 = document.getElementById("pag-1");
  var pag2 = document.getElementById("pag-2");
  var pag4 = document.getElementById("pag-4");
  
  var onChange = function (oldValue, newValue) {
    pag1.classList.toggle("hide", newValue != 4);
    pag2.classList.toggle("hide", newValue <= 4);
    pag4.classList.toggle("hide", newValue >= 4);
  };
  Object.defineProperty(window, "sensorValor", {
    get: function () { return value; },
    set: function (newValue) { 
      if (value != newValue) {
        onChange(value, newValue);
        value = newValue; 
      }
    }
  });
})();

var sensor = document.getElementById("sensor");
sensor.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  sensorValor = parseInt(sensor.value);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="sensor" type="text" value="4" />

<div id="pag-1">Pagina 1</div>
<div id="pag-2" class="hide">Pagina 2</div>
<div id="pag-4" class="hide">Pagina 4</div>
```

No exemplo acima existe um monitoramento das alterações da variavel `sensorValor`, então toda vida que a mesma tiver o seu valor alterado, uma função será sensibilizada.

o `input#sensor` com o evento `input` serve apenas para demostrar o comportamento após a atualização do valor do `sensorValor`.